# Is this a valid jquery statement?

Tags: jquery, css

Can i apply style like this,

`$('#aspnetForm').append($('#facebox .content').html().css({ 'display': 'none' }));` but it didnt work...

**EDIT:**

i am trying to use jquery facebox in asp.net.. i am having issues with the close button.. [hide jquery facebox modal manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346172/hide-jquery-facebox-modal-manually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.html()` returns a string. It doesn't have a `css` method. You can wrap the `html` in another element, hide it, then append it for fine-grained control:

```
var html = $('<div/>').html( $('p:first').html() ).css({'display':'none'}).appendTo('body')
```

You can also manipulate it directly by calling `.css` first, on the element(s).

Comment: i am trying to use jquery facebox in asp.net.. i am having issues with the close button.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346172/hide-jquery-facebox-modal-manually

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do that you can't accomplish by using .hide()?

```
$('#facebox .content').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

`html()` returns a string so you cannot apply a jQuery method on it. Switch the methods:

```
$('#aspnetForm').append($('#facebox .content').css({ 'display': 'none' }).html());
```

Of course you have to be carful with elements inside `'#facebox .content'` that have an ID. An ID has to be unique throughout the page.